# How to test conditional rendering based on URLSearchParams in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameters, query-string

I have a simple application that grabs the ID from the URLSearchParams with this function

```
export default function getLeadIdFromParams(){
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
     return params.get("id");
}
```

This happens inside the  when it renders. It conditonally renders the app so if there is no ID it displays a text message with 'No ID found' and if there is an ID it shows 'ID found'. However I'm having trouble testing it, I can only test the default 'No id' since that is the default url being loaded in the test without an ID. How can I create a test which renders my app with search params that include an ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ID from parameter then you can use `useLocation()` hook which is imported from `react-router-dom` package.